# How to create a dynamic array of arrays in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, loops, dynamic-arrays

I have two arrays already worked into a complex XML parsing script. I was accessing both arrays using this:

```
my @packageNames = (\@listOfValuesRetail, \@listOfValuesAdvisor);
```

I have a loop later that reads through the values and does stuff. Works great.

However, I just got a new requirement that the output loop I'm using has to take one, the other, or both arrays.

Since the line above is hardcoded, I figured the easy thing to do is push only the array(s) I need into a new array, @packageNames, and loop through them:

```
        # add this array to the package name array
        if (@listOfValuesRetail) {
            push(@packageNames, \@listOfValuesRetail);
        }

        # add this array to the package name array
        if (@listOfValuesAdvisor) {
            push(@packageNames, \@listOfValuesAdvisor);
        }
```

etc. But when I do that, and run the script, I get all my output like 10x over, repeated.

The loop that calls the current hard-coded array does so like this:

```
my $length = scalar @packageNames;
for (my $x = 0; $x < $length; $x++) {

    print "Processing package " . ($x+1) . "\n";

    # make an easy to read variable for the current array iteration
    my $currentPackage = $packageNames[$x];

    ...do stuff...
)
```

So the loop already will take more arrays if I have them, but I'm still stuck hard-coding them because I can't figure out how to get the arrays into an array and then get it to work with this simple look without it somehow giving me the data multiple times, like it's reading the length of the array instead of the content or something. Not sure.

This seems so simple to do...how is it done?

Comment: As long as `@packageNames` starts out empty, your two pushes are *exactly* equivalent to the original definition if both `@listOfValuesRetail` and `@listOfValuesAdvisor` are non-empty. There's nothing in what you've shown that would cause *"all my output like 10x over, repeated"* so I suspect you have put your two `if` statements in a loop. Note also that in your `for` loop, `$x` will only ever be 0 and 1. I think you need to show the rest of your program.

Comment: Wow. It was NOT out of the loop and I THOUGHT it was. I read your statement and said nah, but I'll check. Boom, there it is, the "add this array" section above in the loop that reads in the XML and sorts it. Thanks so much. Amazing. Been on this for several hours...so simple.

Comment: Okay I'm glad it's sorted. I've posted it as a solution.

Answer (score 2):

As long as `@packageNames` starts out empty, your two pushes are exactly equivalent to the original definition if both `@listOfValuesRetail` and `@listOfValuesAdvisor` are non-empty.

There's nothing in what you've shown that would cause *"all my output like 10x over, repeated"* so I suspect you have put your two `if` statements inside a loop. Note also that in your `for` loop, `$x` will only ever be 0 and 1.

I think you need to show the rest of your program.